# Solving an eigenvalue problem on a circular domain

Tags: partial-differential-equations, circles, polar-coordinates, boundary-value-problem

I have the given problem to solve:

> Solve the eigenvalue problem for $-\Delta$ on the quarter-circle $x^2+y^2\leq R^2, x\geq 0,\ y\geq 0$ with homogeneous Dirichlet conditions.

---

This is what I did. Since we have a Dirichlet homogeneous condition, we can prepare the *Ansatz* :

$$u(r,\theta)=u(r)\sin2n\theta,$$

for the PDE problem

\begin{equation}
\Delta u=-\lambda u\\
u(r,0)=0, \ \ \ \ u(r,\pi/2)=0 \ \ \ \ \ \  0\leq r\leq R\\  
u(0,\theta)=0, \ \ \ \ \  u(R,\theta)=0 \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ 0\leq \theta \leq\frac{\pi}{2}
\end{equation}

Since, the operator is $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}+\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r^2}+\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta^2}$ we get:

\begin{equation}
u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r-4n^2\frac{1}{r^2}u(r)=-\lambda u(r) \\
u_{rr}+\frac{1}{r}u_r+\bigg(\lambda-\frac{4n^2}{r^2}\bigg)u(r)= 0\\
\end{equation}

So this is a Bessel  equation, and $\lambda>0$, on a bounded domain, so we obtain the general solution, with $v=2n$:

\begin{equation}
R(r)=aJ_v(\sqrt{\lambda}r)
\end{equation}

We then have the form for $u(r,\theta)$:

\begin{equation}
u(r,\theta)=aJ_v(\sqrt{\lambda}r)\sin 2n\theta
\end{equation}

But how do I find this on the quarter-circle and with the right coefficient for $R(r)$?

Any hints appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Hint: use the B.C. on $r=R$

Comment: Got it. Thanks. What puzzles me is that $a$ in front of the Bessel function. Is it just $1$?

Comment: Since the BC are homogeneous, $a$ is arbitrary. Consider the matrix equation $Ax=\lambda x$. If $U$ is a solution, then $aU$ is also a solution. PS, don't put your solution in the question, just self answer and accept.

Answer (score 4):

Using BCs as hinted, we get, where $\alpha_{n,k}$ are the Bessel zeros:

\begin{equation}
\alpha_{n,k}=R(R)\\
\alpha_{n,k}=aJ_v(\sqrt{\lambda}R)\\
\alpha_{n,k}=\sqrt{\lambda}R\\
\lambda=\bigg(\frac{\alpha_{n,k}}{R}\bigg)^2
\end{equation}

So the overall solution is:

\begin{equation}
u(r,\theta)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty J_{2n}\bigg(\frac{\alpha_{n,k}}{R}r\bigg) \sin2n\theta
\end{equation}